# Ordenar tres numeros

Tags: python-3.x

Deseo ordenar tres numeros usando dos funciones, una de cambiar y otra de ordenar, eh intentado con este codigo pero no me resuelve el problema en lo absoluto arrojandome la lista con el mismo orden en el que los puse.

```
def cambiar(x,y):
    aux=x
    x=y
    y=aux
    return x,y

def ordenar(a,b,c):
    if a>b:
        cambiar(a,b)
    elif b>c:
        cambiar(b,c)
    elif a>b:
        cambiar(a,b)
    return (a,b,c)
```

Comment: Seguramente es una tarea en la que te han puesto restricciones. ¿Puedes usar listas? ¿Puedes usar `sort`?

Comment: `def cambiar(x, y): return y, x` es todo lo que necesitas

Comment: Nunca reasignas tus valores `a`, `b` y `c`, por lo cual al final siempre estás devolviendo los mismos valores y en el mismo orden.

Comment: `def ordenar(x, y, z): return sort([x, y, z])`

Comment: Es que facil lo podria hacer con sort, pero quiero hacerlo usando estas dos funciones que presento. Y la asignacion la estoy con la funcion de cambiar, asi que pienso todo deberia salir bien pero creo que no guarda los valores la funcion ordenar cuando actua la funcion cambiar.

Comment: estas confundiendo algunas cosas (los scopes)

Comment: Ummm bueno lo que se de los scopes es que cuando usas una funcion dentro de otra, la funcion que la engloba puede usar los datos pero no cambiarlos... Entonces esta manera de ordenar datos no se podra hacer en python???

Comment: al hacer la definición de variables dentro de una función  son creadas y solo funcionan dentro de ese ámbito.